# What is the functioning of "->" operator in MYSQL joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using Sequelize, and trying to learn from the queries it constructs. I have some complicated one-to-many relationship between few models, so i come across this query:

```
SELECT `ScrumBoard`.`id`, `ScrumBoard`.`title`, `ScrumBoard`.`createdAt`, `ScrumBoard`.`updatedAt`, `ScrumLists`.`id` AS `ScrumLists.id`, `ScrumLists`.`title` AS `ScrumLists.title`, `ScrumLists`.`createdAt` AS `ScrumLists.createdAt`, `ScrumLists`.`updatedAt` AS `ScrumLists.updatedAt`, `ScrumLists`.`ScrumBoardId` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumBoardId`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`id` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.id`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`title` AS
`ScrumLists.ScrumCards.title`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`content` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.content`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`createdAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.createdAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`updatedAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.updatedAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`ScrumListId` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumListId`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`id` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.id`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`title` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.title`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`content` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.content`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`createdAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.createdAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`updatedAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.updatedAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`ScrumCardId` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.ScrumComments.ScrumCardId`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`id` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.id`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`title` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.title`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`color` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.color`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`createdAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.createdAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`updatedAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.updatedAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`createdAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.scrumcard_labels.createdAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`updatedAt` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.scrumcard_labels.updatedAt`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`LabelId` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.scrumcard_labels.LabelId`, `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`ScrumCardId` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.Labels.scrumcard_labels.ScrumCardId` FROM `ScrumBoards` AS `ScrumBoard` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ScrumLists` AS `ScrumLists` ON `ScrumBoard`.`id` = `ScrumLists`.`ScrumBoardId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ScrumCards` AS `ScrumLists->ScrumCards` ON `ScrumLists`.`id` = `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`ScrumListId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ScrumComments` AS `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments` ON `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`id` = `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->ScrumComments`.`ScrumCardId` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `scrumcard_labels` AS `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels` INNER JOIN `Labels` AS `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels` ON `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels`.`id` = `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`LabelId`) ON `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`id` = `ScrumLists->ScrumCards->Labels->scrumcard_labels`.`ScrumCardId`
WHERE `ScrumBoard`.`id` = '1';
```

The query itself is not important, but i would like to understand the meaning of the "->" operator, like in:

> `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`content` AS `ScrumLists.ScrumCards.content`

Comment: The `->` operator serves as an alias for the `JSON_EXTRACT()` function when used with two arguments, a column identifier on the left and a JSON path on the right that is evaluated against the JSON document (the column value). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the `->` has no special meaning. It just belongs to a table alias that is defined in the query, here:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ScrumCards` AS `ScrumLists->ScrumCards`
```

Once the alias is defined, it is used to refer to the corresponding table in the query, like:

```
`ScrumLists->ScrumCards`.`id`
```

Note that this is really a bad choice to use such table alias. `->` is meaningful in MySQL (it's a JSON operator that is a synonym for `JSON_EXTRACT()`). So using it in a table alias requires quoting the identifier everytime you use it. I would strongly suggest changing the table alias to something that is less tricky, and does not require quoting (`ScrumLists_ScrumCards` would be good enough).

Comment: I see...this makes sense. What do you think about the other comments, saying that it's an alias for JSON_EXTRACT()? Is it possible this syntax has a compeltely different usage in other contexts?

Comment: So basically this wasn't even an "operator", but just a name(string) that Sequelize constructed...

Comment: @i.brod: yes, I mentionned that in my answer. That's tricky enough so several people got caught... Not a good design choice for Sequelize in my opinion.

Comment: Why is there even a need for this table alias? I've constructed similar multi-join queries more or less like this one on my own, and never saw any need for a table alias. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path):

**column->path**

The `->` operator serves as an alias for the [JSON_EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function when used with two arguments, a column identifier on the left and a JSON path on the right that is evaluated against the JSON document (the column value). You can use such expressions in place of column identifiers wherever they occur in SQL statements.